# how to create jsonObject according this structure?

Tags: java, json

Here is the structure of wanted JSON string

```
"1" : {
    "Class': "group"
    "text": "test1"
      }
"2" : {
    "Class': "group"
    "text": "test1"
      }
```

How can I create an jsonObject in Java that has this JSON representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSONObject` Class from `net.sf.json.JSONObject` like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

JSONObject childObject=new JSONObject();
childObject.put("class", "group");
childObject.put("text", "test1");

jsonObject.put("1", childObject);
jsonObject.put("2", childObject);

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

Comment: i wrote similar lines, but got errors

              childNode.put("class", element.className());
              childNode.put("text", element.ownText());
              group.put(i, childNode);

becasue "i" is a integer, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can either directly create the structure with Strings, or use a library that will create JSON objects in a more object oriented manner.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library for some discussion on various JSON libraries and their pros/cons.

You can also always go with JSON's official library: http://json.org/java/